# <select> <option> value not appearing on second select box

Tags: php, html, html-select

Background: I have an edit form accessed via a GET from a view form.

The form has two dynamic select fields: `state` and `country`.
When populated, the first select box shows the proper database entry, but the second is blank. Any fields entered after the first select show up as blank.

The code is as follows:

```
include 'connection.php';

$newid = $_GET['id'];

try {

$conec = new Connection();
$con   = $conec->Open();
if ($con) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM certco where id = " . $newid;
$re  = $con->query($sql);
foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="gridstyle.css" />

<form action="processeditcertco.php" method="post">
<fieldset class="block">
<legend>Certification Companies</legend>
<label for="coname">Co Name</label>
<input type="text" name="coname" id="coname" value="<?php echo $row['coname']; ?>" size="65" />

<label for="shortname">Initials</label>
<input type="text" name="shortname" id="shortname" value="<?php echo $row['shortname']; ?>"  size="40" /> 

<label for="addr1">Address 1</label>
<input type="text" name="addr1" id="addr1" value="<?php echo $row['addr1']; ?>"  size="65" />

<label for="addr2">Address 2</label>
<input type="text" name="addr2" id="addr2" value="<?php echo $row['addr2']; ?>"  size="65" />

<label for="city">City</label>
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value="<?php echo $row['city']; ?>"  size="65" />

<label for="zip">Zip</label>
<input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="<?php echo $row['zip']; ?>"  size="65" />

<input type="text" name="country" id="country" value="<?php echo $row['country']; ?>"  size="65" />
// above just to show that the 'country' field has data above select

<label for="state">State</label>
<select id="state" name="state">
<option value="<?php echo $row['state']; ?>"><?php echo $row['state']; ?></option>
// note this is exactly the same as the country code below that does not show data.

<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=money', 'muser', 'mpass');
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * from state where type = "state" or type = "capitol"');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value= " . $row['abbreviation'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select> 

<label for="country">Country</label>
<select id="country" name="country">
<option value="<?php echo $row['country']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country']; ?></option>
//no data shows in this option field.

<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=money', 'muser', 'mpass');
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM country where currencycode > 0 order by menuposition asc");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value= " . $row['alpha3'] . ">" . $row['name'] . " - " . $row['officialname'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input type="submit" class="button"  name="submit" value="Update Record" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<?php
} 
} else {
echo $con;
}
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo $ex->getMessage();
}
$conec->Close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide any link or fiddle to your problem.

Comment: Your current code shows an error in line no. 77 First post your question properly with right code

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're reusing the `$row` variable name. In this part of your code block:

```
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=money', 'muser', 'mpass');
$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * from state where type = "state" or type = "capitol"');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<option value= " . $row['abbreviation'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select> 

<label for="country">Country</label>
<select id="country" name="country">
   <option value="<?php echo $row['country']; ?>"><?php echo $row['country']; ?></option>
//no data shows in this option field.
```

You're using `$row` variable name for the `while()` loop, which means that the original value of `$row` from your `for()` loop will be overwritten and end up being `null` by the time you get to the second select field. Changing your `while` loop to use a different variable name (like `$whileRow`, for example) would prevent the original `$row` variable from being overwritten.

Side note: You're using `$row` again for the second `while()` loop, which is going to again cause issues. You need to be careful about what variable names you use, especially in nested loops, because it can end up producing some weird bugs (as you've seen) that can be hard to track down.

Comment: Hi Briley, Thanks so much. I wasn't thinking that I am actually using the same variables in 3 places. No wonder the field was confused. I've rewritten to open 3 distinct instances, and everything is now showing up. Appreciate your help.